# How to do a simple try / catch with clojure?

Tags: clojure, try-catch

Neither of the code snippets below work with clojure 1.6.0

```
(try
 (prn vv)
  (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e (prn "catch e: " e))
  (finally (prn "finally") )
)
```

I also tried this, after reading some other posts here :

```
(try
 (doall (prn vv))
  (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e (prn "catch e: " e))
  (finally (prn "finally") )
)
```

What am I missing ?

Mike

Comment: What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: What is vv? What do you mean by "they don't work?"

Comment: You are just trying to print vv here.  Did you instead mean to call vv as a function that throws ExceptionInfo?  In any case, please tell us what vv is.

Comment: Actually "w" is supposed to be "vv" (vee-vee), but doesn't matter, the point is that the it should catch an error for trying to print a var that hasn't been defined. I.e. *my* exception handler should fire, instead of the default system

Comment: If vv hasn't been defined, then your code is failing to compile. That's the exception you see. try/catch is runtime, so it never gets to run.

Comment: @Diego, Ok thanks, that explains it.

Answer (score 30):

Catching ExceptionInfo will only catch throwables created with ex-info:

```
(try
  (throw (ex-info "bad" {:a 1 :b 2}))
  (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e
    (prn "caught" e)))
;; => "caught" #<ExceptionInfo clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: bad {:b 2, :a 1}>
```

But not other Exceptions:

```
(try
  (/ 1 "0")
  (catch clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo e
    (prn "caught" e)))
;; => ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.divide (Numbers.java:155)
```

Which you would catch like this:

```
(try
  (/ 1 "0")
  (catch Exception e
    (prn "caught" e)))
;; => "caught" #<ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number>
```

Compilation exceptions happen before evaluation:

```
(try
  w is undefined
  (catch Exception e
    (prn "caught" e)))
;; => CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: w in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/8r/y2d3thln6s3fyrl_s6vknb440000gn/T/form-init6601588363347445596.clj:1:5) 

(try
  (eval 'w)
  (catch Exception e
    (prn "caught" e)))
;; => "caught" #<CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: w in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/8r/y2d3thln6s3fyrl_s6vknb440000gn/T/form-init6601588363347445596.clj:1:5)>
```

You can also have multiple catch clauses to handle different types of exceptions.